# Command line javac works, but Eclipse reports errors

Tags: java, eclipse, compilation

I have a code which works correctly as expected in my command line `java` tool.

The same code when I added to eclipse does throw some error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    Cannot cast from Object to long
```

On the line :

```
    long statusId = (long)json.get("status_id");
```

However with `javac` and `java` command I run the program with successful output.

WTH eclipse is behaving this way! And this is my first eclipse program, kindly help me out.

#### Edit:

Code :

```
public InitOrderResponse connect()
{
    Authentication auth = new Authentication();

    String response = auth.httpBasicAuth(this.constructUrl(),this.key);


    JSONObject json = (JSONObject) JSONValue.parse(response);

    String merchantId = (String)json.get("merchant_id");
    long statusId = (long)json.get("status_id");
    String status = (String)json.get("status");
    String orderId = (String)json.get("order_id");

    initOrderResponse = new InitOrderResponse();
    initOrderResponse.setStatus(status);
    initOrderResponse.setOrderId(orderId);
    initOrderResponse.setStatusId(statusId);
    initOrderResponse.setMerchantId(merchantId);

    return initOrderResponse;
}
```

Comment: Please provide the complete program (or better still, a cut down version with the same error) so that other people can try to reproduce the compilation error.

Comment: I have provided part of the code, where I'm getting the error. The whole program is quite long!

Answer (score 0):

Your eclipse has error/warnings constraints set to give error for some condition, that is not imposed by Java compiler by default.To change these rules, right click on the project, click on properties. Under 'Java Compiler' menu, go to 'errors/warnings'. There you can set constraints for compiler to give errors/warnings.

Comment: You can always change this from Settings in eclipse

Comment: down-voter, can you please give some explanation for down-voting?

Comment: (It wasn't me who downvoted, but ...) You need to say which validation rule you are talking about.  Otherwise this is just speculation, not a real explanation / solution.  That certainly doesn't *look* like a validation rule ... to me.

Comment: Oh! How I can change those settings?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the Jdk versions. When I changed the jdk to point towards the Sun's JDK. Everything works as expected.